# Why is ふとんがふとんだ a pun?

Tags: puns

I was reading an article about how the humour in the Yakuza games gets translated into English, and in the original Japanese a pun is made.

> ふとんがふとんだ

The article says it is a play on words. But I cannot find any explanation online but I do see a reference to it.
I can understand "a table is a table" but this isn't really a pun, it would be equivalent to "calling a spade a spade" in English.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24577/what-does-the-word-%e3%81%b6%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a6%e3%82%8b-mean/24578#24578

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14785/9831

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VpEpAN0Wnc4

Comment: Related: [Dajare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dajare)

Comment: J-learnerには、ですはデスよね？ですよね・・・ *ba-dum-tish*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A pun is a play on words exploiting homophones or similar-sounding words.

The pun in [布団]{ふとん}が[吹っ飛んだ]{ふっとんだ} *The futon was blown off* is that it sounds almost like 布団が布団だ *A futon is a futon*, the latter being a complete tautology.

There are many such popular puns, including

- 犬がいぬ
  *A dog is a dog* v *The dog is gone*
- イルカはいるか
  *A dolphin is a dolphin* v *Is there a dolphin?*
- イクラは幾ら
  *Salmon roe is salmon roe* v *How much is the salmon roe?*
- コンドルは[喜んどる]{よろこんどる}
- ラクダは楽だ
- etc. *ad nauseam*

Comment: The same kind of puns occur in English, too, e.g. "The book about the dragon tended to drag on".

Comment: @l'électeur I didn't copy your translation, even if I ended up with the same translation. Given that the sentence consists of two words, a subject and a predicate, there is not much room for alternative translations, although I did consider "blown away" and "blanket"...

Answer (score 24):

The actual pun is:

> 「ふとんがふ**っ**とんだ」 with a small っ.

and not:

> 「ふとんがふとんだ」 = "A futon is a futon."

which is what you wrote.

The verb prefix 「ふっ」 is explained here:

[What does the word 「ぶったてる」mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24577/what-does-the-word-%e3%81%b6%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a6%e3%82%8b-mean/24578#24578)

To use kanji, the phrase is:

> 「布団{ふとん}がふっ飛{と}んだ。」 = "The futon was blown off."

Thus, it is a legit pun indeed.  It is the kind that small kids like to say.

Comment: A clarification: the verb prefix ふっ here is the contracted combining form of ふき, which is the stem or continuative form of verb 吹【ふ】く _"to blow"_: 吹【ふ】き飛【と】ぶ → 吹【ふ】っ飛【と】ぶ _"to be blown into the air"_.  This is not the same as the ぶっ in ぶったてる, where the ぶっ is the contracted combining form of ぶち, the stem or continuative form of verb 打【ぶ】つ _"to strike, to hit"_: 打【ぶ】ち立【た】てる → 打【ぶ】っ立【た】てる _"to build something in a rough or violent fashion"_ (more idiomatically, perhaps _"to slap something together"_).